# How to check that a point is outside of a route?

Tags: pgrouting

I am newbie in PostGIS and also GIS particularly.

I need to check that a vehicle is outside of a route. This route has been defined in advance, and of course it stores in a table: RROUTEDETAIL. This table contains: ROUTE_ID, LONGITUDE and LATITUDE.

So, when vehicle leaves the route they should be on, the system will give a warning message and then record it into other table.

I imagine to check the point I get with every point store in the RROUTEDETAIL, one by one with ST_DWITHIN. If all check get FALSE value, then the system give a warning message.

Is this the best approach or is there a better idea?

---

For example, this is the point where vehicle leaves: -7.539079, 109.322891 with value tolerance: 0.5. Then I write:

```
    select st_dwithin((select st_makeline(ST_Point(-7.539079, 109.322891))),
        (select st_makeline(ST_Point(foo."TRACKERDATA_LATITUDE",foo."TRACKERDATA_LONGITUDE"))
            from (select ht."TRACKERDATA_LATITUDE", 
                        ht."TRACKERDATA_LONGITUDE"
                        from "HTRACKERDATA" ht
                        left join "RVEHICLE" rv on ht."VEHICLE_ID" = rv."VEHICLE_ID"
                        where ht."VEHICLE_ID" = 106 and 
                        ht."TRACKERDATA_GPSTIME" BETWEEN '2012-01-01 08:00'
                        AND '2012-01-01 17:00'
                        order by ht."TRACKERDATA_GPSTIME", ht."TRACKERDATA_REPORTTIME") as foo), 
        0.5);
```

It always return FALSE. Then I check again with ST_DISTANCE, it gives 99999999999.9 (double precision).

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest connecting all the route points in RROUTEDETAIL to one line geometry. This way only one ST_DWITHIN comparison will be necessary instead of a series of comparisons between points.